Eclipse WindowBuilder Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation
I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2024-06 and WindowBuilder 1.16.0.202405211736.
Note that at my place of work it is extremely difficult to download Eclipse IDE and every time a new version is released I need to hound the relevant people to allow me to download the latest version. I am hoping that when the next version is released, i.e. Eclipse 2024-12, that I will be allowed to install it. Hence I hope to find a resolution that does not invlove upgrading Eclipse to the latest version.
The workspace Java version is 1.8_201 – since the application is built with Java 8 and that cannot be currently changed.
I had no problems working with the Swing Designer until I changed my code to use class javax.imageio.ImageIO to create images from files containing GIF, PNG and JPEG images. Previously the code did not use ImageIO, instead it created a byte array from the file contents and created a javax.swing.ImageIcon from the byte array and extracted the Image from the ImageIcon. (Note that this is legacy code that I inherited.)
The code contains classes that extend the Swing components, e.g. class QtPanel extends class JPanel. (Again, inherited code.)
My application consists of "screens" where each screen is essentially a QtPanel.
When I open such a screen in WindowBuilder, it initially displays the [Java] source code, but when I click on the Design tab, I get the following error.

Here is the stack trace (copied from workspace log file):
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wb.core 4 4 2024-12-03 08:06:29.034
!MESSAGE Designer [1.9.600.202405211736.202412030744]: 313 (Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation).
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 313 (Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation).
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create_usingEnhancer(ThisCreationSupport.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create0(ThisCreationSupport.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create(ThisCreationSupport.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluateJavaInfoUsingCreationSupport(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.addJavaInfo(JavaInfoParser.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4814)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1184)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3259)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.lambda$0(CTabFolder.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create_usingEnhancer(ThisCreationSupport.java:351)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadLocalImage(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3464)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadImage(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3212)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadImageIcon(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3249)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.parseIcon(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:171)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.parseIcon(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:181)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.parseUserPropertiesDocument(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:290)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.loadFile(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:335)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.loadDefaultProperties(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:54)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelUserImplementationDefault.setLookAndFeel(QtLookAndFeelUserImplementationDefault.java:19)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.setLookAndFeel(QtGeneralRoutines.java:4926)
    at qt.presentacion.QtPanel.initialize(QtPanel.java:1670)
    at qt.presentacion.QtPanel.<init>(QtPanel.java:151)
    at qt.presentacion.QtPanel$ByteBuddy$1genscyU.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageWriterSpi could not be instantiated [in thread "main"]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:813)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:729)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1403)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:183)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:107)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:128)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:64)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadLocalImage(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3464)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadImage(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3212)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadImageIcon(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3249)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.parseIcon(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:171)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.parseIcon(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:181)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.parseUserPropertiesDocument(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:290)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.loadFile(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:335)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelRoutines.loadDefaultProperties(QtLookAndFeelRoutines.java:54)
    at qc.desktop.lookandfeel.QtLookAndFeelUserImplementationDefault.setLookAndFeel(QtLookAndFeelUserImplementationDefault.java:19)
    at qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.setLookAndFeel(QtGeneralRoutines.java:4926)
    at qt.presentacion.QtPanel.initialize(QtPanel.java:1670)
    at qt.presentacion.QtPanel.<init>(QtPanel.java:151)
    at qt.development.editors.QtErrorFlowInfoEditorGUI.<init>(QtErrorFlowInfoEditorGUI.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:304)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:725)
    at qt.development.editors.QtPropertyEditorGUIAdapter.initialize(QtPropertyEditorGUIAdapter.java:87)
    at qt.development.editors.QtPropertyEditorGUIAdapter.<init>(QtPropertyEditorGUIAdapter.java:37)
    at qt.development.editors.QtErrorFlowInfoEditor.<clinit>(QtErrorFlowInfoEditor.java:10)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
    at qt.presentacion.QtAbstractBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptor(QtAbstractBeanInfo.java:162)
    at qt.presentacion.QtAbstractBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors(QtAbstractBeanInfo.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getPropertyDescriptors(Introspector.java:576)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetPropertyInfo(Introspector.java:482)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:448)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.getBeanInfo(ReflectionUtils.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.createJavaInfo(JavaInfoUtils.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.parser.ParseFactory.getRootContext(ParseFactory.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1184)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:243)
    ... 55 more

I tried changing the workspace Java. I tried the Java that comes with Eclipse, i.e.
eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.3.v20240426-1530

I also tried using Java 21 from Azul. I got the same error for each Java I tried.
This is the new code I use:
java.awt.Image returnImage = null;
StringBuffer filePath = new StringBuffer("path/to/file");
try (FileInputStream ist = new FileInputStream(filePath.toString())) {
    returnImage = ImageIO.read(ist);  // line 3464
}
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                                              Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.err.println("Ignored: " + ldt.format(formatter));
    e.printStackTrace();
}

The above code includes the line indicated in this line of the stack trace, above:
qc.general.QtGeneralRoutines.loadLocalImage(QtGeneralRoutines.java:3464)

Note that the application runs without error, i.e. when I run the application, method read executes successfully and creates the image. The problem only occurs when I try to open a "screen" in WindowBuilder.
Since the problem is with WindowBuilder, I don't know how to create a reproducible example. Perhaps someone can show me how?
I don't know what other details are required, so please let me know and I will try to supply them.
Basically I want to know what I need to do in order get WindowBuilder to open the designer without crashing.

It tries to read image and fails for some reason. It is bug in eclipse.

@talexmovedtoCodidact according to the stack trace, WindowBuilder fails to instantiate class CLibJPEGImageWriterSpi. Isn't that class part of the JDK?

This should not be a Stack Overflow question, but a bug report like this one with a complete(!) minimal reproducible example and with a pull request that fixes the issues. And if your company does not have the skills to provide a pull request, they should pay someone to do so.
